# Walkthrough: Add-In Command Bars root menu

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, add-in

I am wanting to create a new ArcMap Add-In project with just a custom root menu. According to the walkthrough, I can access the Add-In Command Bars (which has the Menu element) by adding a new item to a project. What kind of project do I create in the first place given the selection of Add-In Types?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can create an actual menu item in the main menu bar with add-ins. You can create a toolbar though and put all your custom add-ins (menu, buttons, combo box) on the toolbar.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Walkthrough_Building_custom_UI_elements_using_add_ins/0001000001ms000000/

See "Creating a custom toolbar"

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Creating a custom toolbar is the same issue - it assumes you have a project to add on in. I will try to create a Multi-Item add-in type so I can add-in a menu (or toolbar), for the lack of a better alternative.